# How can I run a command in server control panel and have the result said in game chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to get my server to type "tps" into the console every 5 minutes and then forward the result to the ingame chat for players to see. Right now if I type tps into the control panel it just returns the result for the control panel to see, how could I get it to forward the result to everyone in game?

Comment: Is `gamerule commandBlockOutput` on? You can also try `logAdminCommands` and `sendCommandFeedback`, even though that shouldn't change anything in your case. The rest depends on what command it actually is. I assume you're using `/tps`, which is a command from a mod? If yes, which mod? Maybe the developer can just add a feature for that. Or they have already done it, but it needs a parameter, like `/tps true`.

Comment: @Fabian Roling `/tps` means "Ticks Per Second" and is a common command on Bukkit/Spigot/Sponge/PaperMC servers for performance monitoring.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true`, and it should work. If it doesn't work, you're probably using a mod because the gamerule above is on by default.